# How to check which part of string is equal to text?

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to check which part of string is equal to text, **from part 0** to `count`.

So I tried this:

```
int count = 1;
int city = 0;
String finall = "gggg,dddd";
String[] separated = finall.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            if (selectedCities.equals(separated[i])){
                city = 1;
            }
```

How to increment each time the i in 1 until it reaches the value of `count`?

Comment: its unclear to me what are you asking. please give some example to your desire solution.

Comment: Please post whole source.

Comment: Your program will crash of you set the index to 3

Comment: ```int count = separated.length``` .  is this what you want??

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to implement like this:

```
String selectedCities = "Miami"; // Selected(Predefine) city
int count = 0;
int city = 0;
String finall = "California,Miami,Delawar,New Jursey";
String[] separated = finall.split(",");
count = separated.length; // find total city in array

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
    if (selectedCities.equals(separated[i])){
        city = 1;
    }
}
System.out.println("City Count = "+city); //Here count will be 1
```

Hope It will be helpful